# Returning data with ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting data from a database using ajax.

In my controller I return:

```
return Products::all();
```

Should I be encoding into JSON or not, if so - how? Or should I leave as is - it's coming through to JS as an object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
return response()->json(Products::all());
```

Comment: Thanks, would returning json be the way to go - why would I not just use an object?

Comment: How you treat your data in your front end? do you use any javascript library? Returning a custom string is not adviced but you can do whatever you want.It depends on what you need to do in front, your app size , etc